# Async n promise change from shortcut

Tags: javascript, async-await, es6-promise

I have this code that I found in an example and it's all in shortcut:

```
async function test1(){
    const p = await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 2000)).then(()=>'test1');
    console.log('Completed test1');
    return p;
}
```

I want to remove the setTimeout and instead have it in non-shortcut so I can add multiple commands to it and do other things besides a timeout...

For example:

```
async function test1(){
    const p = await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve) => {
    // line here
    // another one etc
}
```

How do I change the code above?

Comment: But why you are using async await, because setTimeout is used here just to simulate the promise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
async function test1(){
    const p = await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 2000)).then(()=>'test1');
    console.log('Completed test1');
    return p;
}
```

I think you have not understood this code completely. `setTimeout` is not a shortcut. `new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 2000))` is used to create a promise which will resolve after 2000 ms. You can think of it as an API call which will call the callback after 2000ms

Let's break this code:

```
// A function test1 which is defined async sow you can use await inside it
async function test1(){
    // You can await for promises.
    //  As explained await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 2000)) 
    // is just a promise resolving after 2000ms
    const p = await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 2000))
     // .then block will run after promise gets resolved
     // p will bcome test1
    .then(()=>'test1');
    console.log('Completed test1');
    return p;
}
```

If you want to conditionally resolve the promise and do some calculation you can do that inside setTimeout function:

```
await new Promise(resolve => 
    setTimeout(()=>{
        if('Some consition'){
            resolve('some value')
        }
        else{
            resolve('some other value')
        }
    }, 2000)
)
```

Comment: Almost perfect thanks but what if I don't want to have the timeout and have something else instead? For example resolve => {  // do something here }

Comment: This is completely wrong. The idea with promises / async / await is that you use them to wait it to resolve. Using setTimeout is just wrong at this context. The only way i see this is if it was a example to mimic a promise that executes for 2 seconds.

Comment: @macro that's what i have written setTimeout here is to mimic promise like flow

Comment: `have something else instead`  ->  `await someOtherPromiseThatDoesSomethingElse()`